Local Installation of Drake on macOS Sonoma
I'm a student interested in running the code from the Robotic Manipulation course locally on my Macbook, as opposed to with Deepnote. My machine is using an Apple M3 chip with macOS Sonoma 14.5, and I ran the following commands for installation:
mamba create -n robotic_manipulation python=3.12
mamba activate robotic_manipulation
pip install manipulation==2024.04.22 --extra-index-url https://drake-packages.csail.mit.edu/whl/nightly/
pip install notebook

Then, to ensure meshcat works properly, I ran brew install zmq.
After this, i started a jupyter notebook instance locally, and tried to run the first cell of imports in intro.ipynb [source]. However, I was met with this error trace:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: `itemset` was removed from the ndarray class in NumPy 2.0. Use `arr[index] = value` instead.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: initialization failed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/miniforge3/envs/robotic_manipulation/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydrake/visualization/_model_visualizer.py:28
     23 from pydrake.multibody.tree import (
     24     FixedOffsetFrame,
     25     FrameIndex,
     26     default_model_instance,
     27 )
---> 28 from pydrake.planning import RobotDiagramBuilder
     29 from pydrake.systems.analysis import Simulator

ImportError: initialization failed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 11
      9 from pydrake.systems.framework import DiagramBuilder, EventStatus, LeafSystem
     10 from pydrake.systems.rendering import MultibodyPositionToGeometryPose
---> 11 from pydrake.visualization import MeshcatPoseSliders
     13 from manipulation import running_as_notebook
     14 from manipulation.meshcat_utils import StopButton, WsgButton

ImportError: initialization failed

Would anyone happen to know a fix for this?

It looks like you have numpy2.0, which is still only a release candidate?  https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#history . I'm not sure how pip grabbed that for you.  manipulation (and I believe drake) are only tested with the stable numpy (e.g. 1.26.4)

@RussTedrake It seems like something to look into for whoever maintains manipulation. I ran the following commands in this order:  1) mamba create -n robotic_manipulation python=3.12, 2) mamba activate robotic_manipulation, 3) pip install manipulation. I even ran pip cache purge prior to running these 3 commands. I did notice that after installing numpy 1.26.4 during this pip install process (which it does), it goes to numpy 2.0.0rc2 for some reason. I might just be the first edge case to deal with this : )

I maintain manipulation.  I've gone ahead and added a rule for numpy < 2.0.  I believe pip install manipulation==2024.05.27 --extra-index-url https://drake-packages.csail.mit.edu/whl/nightly/ should work now.

@RussTedrake Thanks so much for your help! I'll update my post to reflect this solution : ) and thanks for open-sourcing such great learning materials

Thanks to @RussTedrake for quickly resolving this issue!
The solution is now:
mamba create -n robotic_manipulation python=3.12
mamba activate robotic_manipulation
pip install manipulation==2024.05.27 --extra-index-url https://drake-packages.csail.mit.edu/whl/nightly/ notebook

